# Create conversation via link in CIrcuit

Tags: circuit-sdk

I'm looking for a way to use a link or something like that to give a Circuit users opportunity to start new coversation fast.

As example there is a link for Telegram:
t.me/{userId}
If user click on this, he will be redirected to conversation with {userId}.

Is there some features on Circuit for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
https://eu.yourcircuit.com/#/email/mymailaddress@circuit.com
```

Please be aware that this link will only work for others but not for yourself (so try with the mail-address of one of your colleagues).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't. A direct conversation with another user can be created by POST /conversation/direct:

```
curl -X POST "https://circuitsandbox.net/rest/v2/conversations/direct" -H "accept: application/json" -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "participant=user_email_or_user_id"
```

You can find more info about the Circuit REST API here:
https://circuit.github.io/rest.html